# Geoserver slow rendering un-cached layers

Tags: geoserver, wms, performance, tomcat

I have GeoServer connected to a SQL Server datastore.  I have a map with 5 Layers, the layers have about 200,000 features total.  The features are styled as simple points or lines - not many lines though. Due to the nature of the data - it changes alot and needs to be instantly current - I don't have caching on.

Geoserver is on a windows server, running on Tomcat. This is all being rendered in the browser using OpenLayers.

I have added some parameters to the CATALINA_OPTS environment variable -

`CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms128m -Xmx2048M -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=36000`

and installed the two recommended Geoserver and JAI and ImageIO extensions.

I have tried rendering as TileWMS and ImageWMS.

Peformance is sub-optimal at best.  It really looks like SQL server returns data very fast, and the bottleneck is GeoServer but I have more questions than answers at this point.  It really doesn't look like the Tomcat service is getting used hard watching it's process in Task Manager.

How can I optimally set up Geoserver to give the best performance? Is there a best practice guide (besides http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/index.html) to point me in the right direction?

Comment: are the attributes in your styles indexed in the DB? Do all 200,000 points need to be displayed at once or could you add some scale dependency

Comment: @IanTurton - there is a table that defines the style attributes, will check for indexes.  No, I don't need to show all 200,000 at once particularly when zoomed out but having found a good pattern for showing less.

Comment: well if you have to do two+ lookups per feature when styling of course it will be slow - work out a better view when zoomed out and all your issues are solved.

Comment: @IanTurton - I was confused sorry, the styles are server side - saved natively in GeoServer and just using the set default styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this presentation:
https://www.slideshare.net/geosolutions/geoserver-in-production-we-do-it-here-is-how-foss4g-2016

In short:

- use scale dependencies to avoid displaying too much data at the same time
- make sure the data is spatially indexed
- switch to postgis if you can

Comment: in slide 12, regarding raster sources, the sizes refer before or faster being compressed?

Comment: Before being compressed.